# Incompatible pointer type for GFile [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]

Tags: gtk

I am trying to use css in a GTK c project.  To load the file, I have

```
GFile *myCssFile = "mystyle.css";
```

The warning comes from compiling with `Gtk+-3.0`.  I'm using

```
pkg-config --cflags gtk+-3.0
```

In addition I get warning

> warning: passing argument 1 of 'g_file_new_for_path' from incompatible pointer type[-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
>
> This warning comes from :
>
> gtk_css_provider_load_from_file(provider, g_file_new_for_path(myCssFile), &error);
>       where provider is defined:  GtkCssProvider *provider;

I'm using Geany for my project.

None of my CSS statements have any effect.

Any thoughts?  I'm not very fluent with CSS nor with Linux on Raspberry Pi.
I feel fairly confident with programming in C though.

Answer (score 1):

> passing argument 1 of 'g_file_new_for_path' from incompatible pointer type

The warning is about the first argument of `g_file_new_for_path`, which is `myCssFile`, and that you defined this way:

```
GFile *myCssFile = "mystyle.css";
```

The problem is that is that a GFile is not a simple file path, it's an object representing a file/directory that can be manipulated. In other words, you first need to create a [GFile](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#GFile.description) object from a path using [`g_file_new_for_path`](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/GFile.html#g-file-new-for-path).